# How to insert multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a table name :: users with id and name in mysql , the id is primary key with auto increment and name is varchar(50) and now i have a bunch of unique names almost 70 , how should i insert it in bulk , i know basic statements but i didn't found something best related to this problem

mysql> desc users;

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Where did your unique names data row?

Comment: name is there in the column i have not made it unique but the list i have i checked its unique

Answer (score 2):

The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) says:

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of comma-separated column values, with lists enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Also you can use the [Insert ... Select ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c)
SELECT a,b,c
FROM ...
```

Comment: I know this approach but the problem in this is that i have to put every time insert into table (id,name) values (1,"vk"),(2,gab)...like this so 70 times i need to add it

Comment: Well, if it's just 70, I'd use a regexp, or a macro to create the proper SQL string. Also, certain editors have "column mode" (usually Alt-mouse drag) that eases the formatting manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
insert into users (name) values ("name1"),("name2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the information you want to insert inside file you might use `LOAD DATA INFILE`

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'InfoToBeInsertedInsideDB.csv' 
INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The `csv` looks like:

[image]